# How to run coutdown time from remaining time in swift?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nstimer, countdown, nstimeinterval

I have remaining time in "dd HH:mm:ss" format, from which i have to run countdown time. I am using this code

```
func updateCounter() {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd HH:mm:ss"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(timerString)
    let timeLeft = date!.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    lblTImer.text = timeLeft.time
    lblTImer.font = UIFont.init(name: "Gotham-Book", size: 20)
}
```

for updating label

```
extension NSTimeInterval {
    var time:String {
        return String(format:"%02d : %02d : %02d : %02d", Int((self/86400)), Int((self/3600.0)%24), Int((self/60.0)%60), Int((self)%60))
    }

}
```

but i am not getting correct time, correct me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: what means not correct time? you get nil or it is always 2 days?

Comment: if i pass "1 22:26:20" in time string then i get "10957:16:57:22" in label, its like no of days passed is 1 and i am getting 10957 days

Answer (score 0):

Because you've been using `NSDateFormatter` incorrectly. For one there's no year and month in your `timerString`, only hour, minute, second. For another, you forgot to adjust for the timezone.

Your `timeString` represents a time duration, in seconds and formatted into `day hour:minute:second` style. As far I know, Cocoa / UITouch doesn't provide a suitable formatter for that. But it's simple to build one:

```
extension NSTimeInterval {
    init(fromString str: String) {
        let units: [Double] = [1, 60, 3600, 86400]
        let components = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " :")).reverse()

        self = zip(units, components)
                .map { $0 * (Double($1) ?? 0) }
                .reduce(0, combine: +)
    }

    var time:String {
        return String(format:"%02d : %02d : %02d : %02d", Int((self/86400)), Int((self/3600.0)%24), Int((self/60.0)%60), Int((self)%60))
    }
}


let timerString = "1 22:26:20"

let timeLeft = NSTimeInterval(fromString: "1 22:26:20")
print(timeLeft)         // 167180.0
print(timeLeft.time)    // 01 : 22 : 26 : 20
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i use this with timer, which change timeLeft value?
By now its only giving "01:22:26:20"

Comment: That's a different question. What you asked here is how to convert a string  to the number of seconds